# How to lock a method in python (prevent it to be overwritten)?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In this example, I would like to avoid the `# Oops` eventuality.

```
def foo():
    return "foo"

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):        
        setattr(self, 'foo', foo)

    def bar(self):
        return "bar"
```

-

```
>>> x = MyClass()
>>> x.foo()
>>> x.foo = 2 # Oops    
>>> x.foo()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

How can I prevent my methods to be overwritten by mistake?

Comment: Have you tried making it a property without setter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `x.foo` a property, without specifying a setter. However it is quite tricky to do it dynamically:

```
def add_property(inst, name, method):
    '''
    Adds a property to a class instance.
    Property must be added to the CLASS.
    '''
    cls = type(inst)

    if not hasattr(cls, '__perinstance'):
        cls = type(cls.__name__, (cls,), {})
        cls.__perinstance = True
        inst.__class__ = cls

    setattr(cls, name, property(method))
```

And then instead of just doing `setattr` do it like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        add_property(self, 'foo', lambda _ : 2)
```

(for more realistic use, replace the `lambda` function with the
function or method returning the value for `foo`)

Output:

```
>>> o=MyClass()
>>> o.foo
2
>>> o.foo=3
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if passed to `setattr` attribute name is already exists in class (and instance if needed) `__dict__` and do not rewrite it in that case:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name not in self.__class__.__dict__ and name not in self.__dict__:
            super(MyClass, self).__setattr__(name, value)
```

test:

```
>>> x = MyClass()
>>> x.foo = foo # equal to your __init__ setattr call
>>> x.foo()
'foo'
>>> x.foo = 2
>>> x.foo()
'foo'
```